# Create a new Bitbucket Pipeline using API

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-api

I would like to create a new pipeline using API for SAST scan. Is this possible using the API. Any pointers to the relevant BB API docs or any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

So, there isn't any official API endpoint for creating a new pipeline.

Here are Bitbucket cloud API docs: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/

Here you will find information on how to set up your first pipeline:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines/

I hope that helps!